# join() and start() methods

Tags: java, multithreading

Code 1:

```
// Create a second thread.
class NewThread implements Runnable {
    Thread t;
    NewThread() {
        // Create a new, second thread
        t = new Thread(this, "Demo Thread");
        System.out.println("Child thread: " + t);
        t.start(); // Start the thread
    }
    // This is the entry point for the second thread.
    public void run() {
        try {
            for(int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
                System.out.println("Child Thread: " + i);
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Child interrupted.");
        }
        System.out.println("Exiting child thread.");
    }
}

class ThreadDemo {
    public static void main(String args[ ] ) {
        new NewThread(); // create a new thread
        try {
            for(int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
                System.out.println("Main Thread: " + i);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Main thread interrupted.");
        }
        System.out.println("Main thread exiting.");
    }
}
```

Code 1(Output):

```
Child thread: Thread[Demo Thread,5,main]
Main Thread: 5
Child Thread: 5
Child Thread: 4
Main Thread: 4
Child Thread: 3
Child Thread: 2
Main Thread: 3
Child Thread: 1
Exiting child thread.
Main Thread: 2
Main Thread: 1
Main thread exiting.
```

Code 2:

```
// Using join() to wait for threads to finish.
class NewThread implements Runnable {
    String name; // name of thread
    Thread t;
    NewThread(String threadname) {
        name = threadname;
        t = new Thread(this, name);
        System.out.println("New thread: " + t);
        t.start(); // Start the thread
    }
    // This is the entry point for thread.
    public void run() {
        try {
            for(int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
                System.out.println(name + ": " + i);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(name + " interrupted.");
        }
        System.out.println(name + " exiting.");
    }
}

class DemoJoin {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        NewThread ob1 = new NewThread("One");
        NewThread ob2 = new NewThread("Two");
        NewThread ob3 = new NewThread("Three");
        System.out.println("Thread One is alive: "
            + ob1.t.isAlive());
        System.out.println("Thread Two is alive: "
            + ob2.t.isAlive());
        System.out.println("Thread Three is alive: "
            + ob3.t.isAlive());
        // wait for threads to finish
        try {
            System.out.println("Waiting for threads to finish.");
            ob1.t.join();
            ob2.t.join();
            ob3.t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Main thread Interrupted");
        }
        System.out.println("Thread One is alive: "
            + ob1.t.isAlive());
        System.out.println("Thread Two is alive: "
            + ob2.t.isAlive());
        System.out.println("Thread Three is alive: "
            + ob3.t.isAlive());
        System.out.println("Main thread exiting.");
    }
}
```

Code2(Output) - this one is changing with every run:

```
New thread: Thread[One,5,main]
New thread: Thread[Two,5,main]
New thread: Thread[Three,5,main]
Thread One is alive: true
Two: 5
One: 5
Thread Two is alive: true
Thread Three is alive: true
Waiting for threads to finish.
Three: 5
Two: 4
One: 4
Three: 4
Two: 3
One: 3
Three: 3
Three: 2
One: 2
Two: 2
One: 1
Three: 1
Two: 1
Two exiting.
One exiting.
Three exiting.
Thread One is alive: false
Thread Two is alive: false
Thread Three is alive: false
Main thread exiting.
```

Hi, there. I'd like you to look at these codes. The question is: How come start() method acts differently? As I understand main thread should be the running one until method sleep(), join(), etc. "happens", and when that happens Scheduler should get next thread for Ready queue and set her as Thread::running. Is it because of join() method or what? I have basic knowledge of threads, yet this code bugs me very much. Thank you in advance.

Comment: your understanding is incorrect, the scheduler can swap threads out pretty much whenever it wants. did you read the answers to the question that your previous question was a duplicate of?

Comment: I did. But I didn't understand it quite well, as you can see. And yet, you didn't explain why are these 2 codes different. Why do I get the same output in code 1 and why not in code 2?

Comment: Your question is too open ended.  You are more likely to get an answer if you post _one_ program, tell us what you expect it to print out, and tell us how it fails to meet your expectation.   (e.g., ask us "why did it print A before it printed B" instead of asking "why are these different?")

Comment: P.S.:  Doing `t = new Thread(this); t.start();` inside an object constructor is a Bad Idea.  Google for "leaking this in constructor" to find out why.

Comment: *this code bugs me* Pun intended?

Comment: No puns intended. :D Anyways. I think I got the answer now, so thank you all.